# Spatial mapping of Indian districts with yield value

Tags: r

Actually I am learning spatial mapping in R , and trying the concepts. I want to add the data from my excel sheet to the shape file of India which I have.

Please help me how can I add the yield data available I have for different district in India to the Indian Map. However, data is not available for all the states. I want to show whatever data I have in the map.

Code is below:

```
p<-readOGR("C:\\R_script\\IN_Admin2_2019\\IN_Admin2.shp")
plot(p)
shape_merged <- merge(p, geo)

ggplot() +geom_path(data = p, aes(x = long, y = lat) + geom_tile(shape_merged, mapping = 
aes(x=long, 
y=lat, fill=Yield))
```

Data:
[image]

Regards and Thanks,
Ranjeet

Comment: look into the packages `sf` (to create spatial datasets) and `dplyr` (for left_joins). I'm afraid your question is not quite clear enough to give you a more clear answer. Also, please only tag R for this question, you are not using Python.

Comment: using library(tigris) you can use geo_join(spatial_data, data_frame, by_sp, by_df, by = NULL, how = "left")

Comment: used this with the shapefile imported in p variable and data frame is in geo. still throwing error.'p<-readOGR("C:\\R_script\\IN_Admin2_2019\\IN_Admin2.shp")
plot(p)
geo_join(p, Yield, by_p, by_Yield, by = NULL, how = "left")'